# Implementing validations in Angular 2 multi-select drop-down

Tags: angular, multi-select

I was wondering bootstrap validations can be implemented in Angular 2 multi-select dropdown by cuppa labs. I went through the documentation but was unable to find any.
Basically I want to highlight the dropdown in red if user does not select any values like for a normal input I can use `[ngClass]="{'is-invalid': someThing.invalid}"`. Here is my HTML and what I have tried:

```html
<angular2-multiselect name="countries"
  [(ngModel)]="myModel.countries" #countries2="ngModel"
  presentInCountries [data]="countries"
  [settings]="presentInCountriesdropdownSettings"
  (ngModelChange)="multiselectChangeCountries($event)">
</angular2-multiselect>
```

I tried setting a boolean to true if selected countries is 0 and then apply:

```js
this.presentInCountriesdropdownSettings.classes += ' is-invalid';
```

But this does not work. Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ReactiveForm` and `Required` validator like this:

> **Component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  /*########### Form ###########*/
  registrationForm = this.fb.group({
    countryName: ['', [Validators.required]]
  })
```

> **Component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <angular2-multiselect name="countries"
     formControlName="countryName"
     presentInCountries [data]="countries"
     [settings]="presentInCountriesdropdownSettings"
     (ngModelChange)="multiselectChangeCountries($event)">
  </angular2-multiselect>
</form>
```

Comment: But how this apply red border if validation fails?

Comment: use angular material select, the Red border is a default

Comment: Sorry cannot use angular material, have to stick to angular2-multiselect